# How to properly animate a table in beamer with growing horizontal and vertical borders?

Tags: tables, beamer

I animate the fields of the table column by column. But I am struggling to make the vertical lines only appear with the respective column. Also, I want the horizontal lines to be growing when each new column appears. In short, the *empty* boxes should not appear in any of the slides. Is there a neat and reusable solution for that?
Thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>{\usetheme{Madrid}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{3 columns}{}
\centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \onslide<.(1)->Column A & \onslide<+(1)->{Column B} & \onslide<+(1)->{Column C} \\  \hline
    \onslide<.(-2)-.(1)>{11} & \onslide<.-.(1)>{12}   & \onslide<.(1)-.(1)>{13}    \\
    \hline
    \onslide<.(-2)-.(1)>{21} & \onslide<.-.(1)>{22}   & \onslide<.(1)-.(1)>{23}    \\ 
    \hline
    \onslide<.(-2)-.(1)>{31} & \onslide<.-.(1)>{32}   & \onslide<.(1)-.(1)>{33}    \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You might be interested in "23.4  Uncovering Tagged Formulas Piecewise" and "23.5  Uncovering a Table Rowwise" from the `beamer` user manual.

Answer (score 1):

A very dirt solution that work using the `texpos` package (see [documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/textpos)). With this solution you must center the table manually on the frame using the provided grid (created with Ti*k*Z).
You must create three tables with 1, 2 and 3 columns that overlap on different slides.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>{\usetheme{Madrid}}
\newcommand{\nx}{40}%number of division on x axis
\newcommand{\ny}{10}%number of division on y axis
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\TPGrid{\nx}{\ny}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\newcommand\myGrid{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    overlay,
    remember picture,
    shift={(current page.north west)},
    ]
    \tikzmath{
        \sdx=\nx-1;
        \sdy=\ny-1;
    }
    \draw[very thin, blue!10, xstep=\TPHorizModule, ystep=\TPVertModule]
    (current page.south west) grid (current page.north east);
    \draw[very thin, red!50, xstep=5*\TPHorizModule, ystep=5*\TPVertModule]
    (current page.south west) grid (current page.north east);
    \foreach \x in {1,2,...,\sdx} {
    \node [xshift=\x*\TPHorizModule,label=below:\textcolor{white}{\tiny\x},inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] at 
    (current page.north west){};
    }
    \foreach \y in {1,2,...,\sdy} {
    \node [yshift=-\y*\TPVertModule,label=right:\tiny\y,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] at 
    (current page.north west) {};
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{3 columns}{}
%\myGrid% <------uncomment and manually center the table on the frame changing \posX and \posY 
\def\posX{10.5}
\def\posY{3}
\begin{textblock}{20}(\posX,\posY)
\onslide<1>{
\begin{flushleft}
\begin{tabular}{|c|}
    \hline
    Column A    \\  
    \hline
    11          \\
    \hline
    21          \\ 
    \hline
    31          \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{flushleft}
}
\end{textblock}

\begin{textblock}{20}(\posX,\posY)
\onslide<2>{
\begin{flushleft}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
    \hline
    Column A    & Column B      \\  
    \hline
    11          & 12            \\
    \hline
    21          & 22            \\ 
    \hline
    31          & 32            \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{flushleft}
}
\end{textblock}

\begin{textblock}{20}(\posX,\posY)
\onslide<3>{
\begin{flushleft}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    Column A    & Column B  & Column C  \\  
    \hline
    11          & 12        & 13        \\
    \hline
    21          & 22        & 23        \\ 
    \hline
    31          & 32        & 33        \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{flushleft}
}
\end{textblock}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This does not solve your problem, but if the lines are not essential (some say they are useless), then the following code is much lighter.
It is necessary to load the `array` package.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>{\usetheme{Madrid}}

\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{3 columns}{}
\centering
    \begin{tabular}{>{\onslide<1->}c >{\onslide<2->}c >{\onslide<3->}c}
%    \hline
    Column A & Column B & Column C \\ % \hline
    11 & 12   & 13    \\
%    \hline
    21 & 22   & 23    \\ 
%    \hline
    31 & 32  & 33    \\
%    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nevertheless, neat and easily extendable for future. Thanks for sharing.